# Is it safe to eat raw, soaked grains and seeds such as buckwheat?

Tags: raw, seeds, grains, soaking

I was wondering about the safety of frequently eating grains or seeds that have been soaked overnight, but not cooked. I'm thinking about buckwheat, barley, spelt, rye...

Soaking in water with a bit of vitamin c or apple cider vinegar should reduce the phytic acid content enough. Is there anything else that would be of concern ?

Comment: Look up 'muesli'… if you can put it in muesli, you can eat it raw.

Comment: Buckwheat isn’t a grain...

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon and quite safe, but then the ones I have soaked (and sprouted) are not the ones you have listed. I have sprouted black sesame, fenugreek and some lentils. I use a lot of information from [sproutpeople](https://sproutpeople.org/seeds/). You could try them.